# Get height of the div on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm

I have a function that resizes divs depending on how high (in pixels) other divs with the same class are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function resizeTheDivs(tag){
        // first get the tags to adjust
        var $tags = $('.' + tag);
        var $new_height = 0;
        // find out which one is largest
        $('.' + tag).each(function(){
            $(this).height() > $new_height ? $new_height = $(this).height() : null;
        });
        // make all others that height
        $tags.height($new_height);
        // I console.log($new_height) here sometimes
    }

    // resize divs on document load
    $(document).ready(function(){
        resizeTheDivs('the-class');
    });
    // resize divs on window resize
    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizeTheDivs('the-class');
    });

</script>
```

The divs resize correctly on page load, but when `console.log($new_height)` fires from the window resize function, the `$new_height` is not changed.

Context: There are 3 divs (floated left, so next to each other with 33% width) that contain text in `p` tags. So when I resize the browser width, the text gets 'longer', but the javascript function isn't picking up the new heights of the divs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use CSS Flex? Also you call `resizeTheCats`, but you provide not cats function, only `resizeTheDiv`.

Comment: @Justinas, thanks I've corrected the function names (I changed them here from my original code). I'm not familiar with flex, so I went straight for jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the `height` to `auto` before measuring it, or else it will always return the fixed value you set in `$(document).ready`:

```
function resizeTheDivs(tag){
    // first get the tags to adjust
    var $tags = $('.' + tag);
    var $new_height = 0;
    // find out which one is largest
    $('.' + tag).each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
        $(this).height() > $new_height ? $new_height = $(this).height() : null;
    });
    // make all others that height
    $tags.height($new_height);
    // I console.log($new_height) here sometimes
}
```